# How to disable the jquery.validate error indications

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I had used Jquery validate plugin to check out error and i had submitted the thing via ajax. since i am using same form for two purpose. One for add form, and another for edit form.

Once user check on submit button on add form. some error would be display on screen. We he/she toggle to edit form. I need to wash out that error and use to jquery.validate as a fresh.  Remember i am using single validation script for both add and edit form. Form is same but during submission different action occurs.

I need to wash out errors of jquery.validate while toggling add to edit screen or viceversa.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [resetForm()](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/resetForm).

> Resets the controlled form.
>
> Resets input fields to their original value
> (requires form plugin), removes
> classes indicating invalid elements
> and hides error messages.

Usage

```
var validator = $(...).validate();
validator.resetForm();
```

Dependency: [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api).